# Electron w/ Broadcast Channels - Can't create BroadcastChannel in an opaque origin

Tags: javascript, electron, broadcast-channel

I am new to Electron and have some code to create a new window. I'd like for the window to open a BroadcastChannel but am getting the error:

```
Failed to construct 'BroadcastChannel': Can't create BroadcastChannel in an opaque origin
```

The code looks like this:

**main.ts**

```js
...
function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 600,
    width: 800,
    show: false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'renderer.js'),
    },
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  // mainWindow.loadURL("app://a/static/main.html");
  mainWindow.loadFile('../static/main.html');

  mainWindow.on('ready-to-show', () => {
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    mainWindow.show();
  });
```

**renderer.js**

```js
...
window.onload = () => {
  const app = <App />;

  document.body.appendChild(app);

  const daemonChannel = new BroadcastChannel('Daemon');
  const rendererChannel = new BroadcastChannel('Renderer');

  daemonChannel.onmessage = (e) => {
    document.body.appendChild(<p>{e.data}</p>);
    rendererChannel.postMessage(`hello back ${e.data}`);
  };
};
```

This is working on my mac laptop but not multiple Windows development machines?

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out, the main.html file wasn't resolving correctly:

```
mainWindow.loadFile('../static/main.html');
```

I made sure that file exists and it now works.